# How can i fix the: ERROR: Failed building wheel for cuvec

Tags: python, pip, subprocess, python-wheel, pyproject.toml

I want to install a package. But  there is the following error.
I could not fix this error. Any help is appreciated.

Python version: 3.9

Ubuntu version: 20.04

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for cuvec
> Failed to build cuvec
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for cuvec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

> × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> full command: //home/pc6/yes/bin/python /home/pc6/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/**pip-runner**.py install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-4ou8yuqy/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel 'setuptools_scm[toml]>=3.4' 'cuvec>=2.5.0' 'ninst>=0.10.0' 'numpy>=1.14' 'miutil[cuda]>=0.4.0' 'scikit-build>=0.11.0' 'cmake>=3.18' ninja
> cwd: [inherit]
> Installing build dependencies ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error

> × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
> │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> See above for output.

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score -1):

you need to install pyproject

```
pip install pyproject
```

Comment: Thanks. I installed pyproject. But the error was not fixed!!!